# using oledb inside class

Tags: c#, sql, class, oledb

I have the code bellow and i get this error:

```
Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException "syntax error"
```

and i don't know what i did wrong. it suppose to pull infomation from table. I used the same method on the whole project, and just in this, it makes me troubles...

```
    class Codons
{
    private bool start, end;
    private string codon1, codon3, triplet1, triplet2, triplet3;
    private string triplet4, triplet5, triplet6, fullName;
    private OleDbConnection dataconnection;


    public Codons(string letter)
    {
        this.start = false;
        this.end = false;
        this.dataconnection = new OleDbConnection();
            this.dataconnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
            this.dataconnection.Open();


            string sql = "SELECT  tblCodons.codonsCodon3, " +
            "tblCodons.codonsTriplet1, tblCodons.codonsTriplet2, tblCodons.codonsTriplet3, " +
            "tblCodons.codonsTriplet4, tblCodons.codonsTriplet5, tblCodons.codonsTriplet6, " +
            "tblCodons.codonsFullName, tblCodons.codonsStart, tblCodons.codonsEnd"
            + " FROM tblCodons"
            + " WHERE tblCodons.codonsCodon1="+letter;

            OleDbCommand mycomm = new OleDbCommand(sql, dataconnection);
            OleDbDataReader dataReader = mycomm.ExecuteReader();
            dataReader.Read();
            this.codon1 = letter;
            this.codon3 = dataReader.GetString(0);
            this.triplet1 = dataReader.GetString(1);

            if (dataReader.IsDBNull(2))
                this.triplet2 = "     ";
            else
                this.triplet2 = dataReader.GetString(2);

            if (dataReader.IsDBNull(3))
                this.triplet3 = "     ";
            else
                this.triplet3 = dataReader.GetString(3);

            if (dataReader.IsDBNull(4))
                this.triplet4 = "     ";
            else
                this.triplet4 = dataReader.GetString(4);

            if (dataReader.IsDBNull(5))
                this.triplet5 = "     ";
            else
                this.triplet5 = dataReader.GetString(5);

            if (dataReader.IsDBNull(6))
                this.triplet6 = "     ";
            else
                this.triplet6 = dataReader.GetString(6);

            this.fullName = dataReader.GetString(7);
            this.start = dataReader.GetBoolean(8);
            this.end = dataReader.GetBoolean(9);
            dataReader.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
+ " WHERE tblCodons.codonsCodon1="+letter
```

You are creating an SQL clause that looks like this.

```
...WHERE tblCodons.codonsCodon1=A
```

which is invalid SQL. Strings literals in SQL must be quoted propery, i.e.

```
...WHERE tblCodons.codonsCodon1='A'
```

To do this, you can either manually add the single quotes **and** make sure to properly escape all single quotes in the string letter (unless you want to have to deal with [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/))...

... **or** (much better) you use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx):

```
+ " WHERE tblCodons.codonsCodon1 = ?"; 

OleDbCommand mycomm = new OleDbCommand(sql, dataconnection); 
mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("codonsCodon1", letter);
```

In addition, you should check the return value of `dataReader.Read()` instead of just calling it:

```
if (!dataReader.Read()) {
     // replace this with more useful error reporting, maybe throwing an exception
     MessageBox.Show("No codon for this letter found.");
     return;
}
```

Comment: i get this error" No data exists for the row/column." and i added this:'mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("tblCodons.codonsCodon1", letter);'

Comment: i tried it and i get this error `No data exists for the row/column.  `

Answer (score 1):

Since you're building your SQL Query as a string, I'm guessing you have some invalid SQL syntax in `letter`. Once you append that value to the query, it causes the syntax error you're seeing.

I would take a look at this post about [Parameterized Queries (OleDb)](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/09/28/Parameterized-Queries-_2800_Oracle_2C00_-SQLServer_2C00_-OleDb_2900_.aspx). That is the correct way to pass parameters to a query that will avoid this (and other obvious SQL Injection attacks) in your application.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably that you enter the value of `letter` without quotes. It then treats the content of `letter` as a function. Since it can't find the function, it throws a syntax error exception.

Try closing `letter` in quotes ("letter")

Comment: i tried it and i get this error `No data exists for the row/column.`